# Gateway M275 won't charge. Replace DC input jack or power cable connector?

Tags: laptop-repair, power-jack

When I plug in my Gateway M275 convertible tablet, it has trouble charging. I hear odd squeal-y noises coming from the back of the unit if it's plugged in, and the charging indicator turns on and off intermittently and seemingly randomly.

I've identified two possible suspects, partly by disassembling the machine and partly by research:

1. It is common for the DC input jack on this model to fail, but I don't see any issues with the solder connections on the system board. I haven't been able to get a good look inside the jack yet, so it's possible there is internal damage (from the once or twice the cord got yanked in years past).
2. The laptop-end connector on my power supply is not exactly the way it should  be. The cable has been stressed and bent back away from the plug, and the rubbery-plastic plug casing is deformed. Is it likely that replacing the plug (cutting off the old and attaching a new one) will solve the problem without having to solder delicate components on a delicate system board?

So in short, which is more likely to be the problem: **DC input jack** or **power cable plug**? Or should I **replace both**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try another generic Laptop AC adapter, if you can buy one locally try it, if it does not solve the charging issue, return it, you now know it is a possible DC jack problem.

If it does solve charging, decide to return it or repair the original.